# SharePoint 2016 modified no. of days

Tags: list, column, library

A quick one I hope. Is there an OOB setting to change the modified field in lists and libraries so it just shows the date instead of saying the number of days on occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply go to your library/list settings.

Open the modified column.

Change it to standard as below and save it.

[image]

It will show the date in date format.